# Why isn't my javascript calculator working with the base.html?

Tags: javascript, html, django

So awhile ago I made a javascript calculator and now I'm re-using it in another project. The problem is, it doesn't even show up on the page anymore. This is the code for the calc.html file.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
</div>
<div id="JSCalc">
    <form name="calculator">
        <input type="text" name="answer"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value=" 7" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '7'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 8" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '8'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 9" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '9'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" *" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '*'"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value=" 4" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '4'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 5" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '5'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 6" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '6'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" -" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '-'"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value=" 1" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '1'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 2" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '2'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" 3" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '3'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" +" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '+'"/>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value=" 0" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '0'"/>
        <input type="button" value=" C" onclick="calculator.answer.value = ''"/>
        <input type="button" value=" =" onclick="calculator.answer.value = eval(calculator.answer.value)"/>
        <input type="button" value=" /" onclick="calculator.answer.value += '/'"/>
        <br />
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And this is the base.html file it's extending from. Note that this wasn't written by me, I'm just trying to get the calculator to work with it and I'm not seeing what's stopping it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            {% if indexPage %}
                Sales Tracker
            {% else %}
                {% block title %}{% endblock %} &sdot; Sales Tracker
            {% endif %}
        </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/foundation.min.css" %}'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/app.css" %}'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Top Nav Bar -->
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-left">
                <input type="submit" class="blue" value="Calculator" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/calc','_blank','height=425,width=425')" />
                <a href="/">Sales Tracker</a>
                </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/account/">Account</a>
                    <a href="/logout/">Logout</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="/register/">Register</a>
                    <a href="/login/">Login</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- [END] Top Nav Bar -->

        {% block default_content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <script src='{% static "js/vendor/jquery.js" %}'></script>
        <script src='{% static "js/vendor/what-input.js" %}'></script>
        <script src='{% static "js/vendor/foundation.min.js" %}'></script>
        <script src='{% static "js/app.js" %}'></script>
        {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it because you are using {% block body %} from calc file and that block has never been called from your base file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you need to access:

> http://localhost:8000/calc.html (calc.html)

Well you have not defined that right? You are trying to access:

> http://localhost:8000/calc (calc)

Your code:

```
<input type="submit" class="blue" value="Calculator" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/calc','_blank','height=425,width=425')" />
```

**Try this :**

```
<input type="submit" class="blue" value="Calculator" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/calc.html','_blank','height=425,width=425')" />
```